# How do I loop over an input array using a UDF in FaunaDB?

Tags: user-defined-functions, facebook-fql, faunadb

I have a question about mapping an array of ID's (inputdata) and returning all related documents to those ID's. I have a UDF set up to retrieve the documents for a single ID and was hoping some tweaking would make that work. I can't seem to figure out how to map over the inputdata and create a variable (data:) to store the new array of documents. Any help is appreciated. Here is the single entry UDF which works:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["inputdata"],
    Let(
      {
        data: Map(
          Paginate(
            Match(
              Index("certificate_by_dealer"),
              Ref(Collection("Dealers"), Select("dealer", Var("inputdata")))
            )
          ),
          Lambda(["ref"], Get(Var("ref")))
        )
      },
      Select(["data"], Var("data"))
    )
  )
)
```

Is there a simple...or any solution to make this work for an array of ID's as inputdata?

Call function is:

```
Call("user_dealers_all_certificates", {
  ids: [301393590798516736, 301393590798516749]
}
```

Unfortunately I get no results. (Adding quotes solved the issue)

Here is implementing the suggested UDF:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["inputdata"],
    Let(
      { dataIds: Select("ids", Var("inputdata")) },
      Union(
        Map(
          Var("dataIds"),
          Lambda(
            ["id"],
            Select(
              ["data"],
              Paginate(
                Match(
                  Index("certificate_by_dealer"),
                  Ref(Collection("Dealers"), Var("id"))
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Adding quotes created a proper response:

```
Call("user_dealers_all_certificates", {ids: ["302122229239382536", "301394099049595400"]})

[
  Ref(Collection("Certificate"), "302122488174739977"),
  Ref(Collection("Certificate"), "302120872550859273")
]
```

However the GraphQL query returns bad data:

```
query {
  allUserDealersCertificate(data: {ids: ["302122229239382536", "301394099049595400"]}){
   data {
_id
  }
}
}
```

response:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Lambda expects an array with 1 elements. Array contains 4.",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "invalid argument"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

GraphQL error without paginated: true in schema:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allUserDealersCertificate": [
      null,
      null
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type (line 3, column 5):\n    _id\n    ^",
      "path": [
        "allUserDealersCertificate",
        0,
        "_id"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable type (line 3, column 5):\n    _id\n    ^",
      "path": [
        "allUserDealersCertificate",
        1,
        "_id"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what `inputdata` looks like? You're using `Select` as if there are objects inside `inputdata`.

Comment: I have edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try wrapping your hard-coded ids in quotation marks?

Comment: That seems to have made it work. However there is an issue with the GraphQL response. I have edited the question.

Comment: @eskwayrd Any ideas on the GraphQL error? It seems to be the last hurdle to getting this "function"ing.

Comment: Have you specified that the GraphQL query is using pagination? If so, your function has to accept the `size`, `before`, and `after` parameters too. See: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/directives/d_resolver

Comment: Thanks for the response. The only reason that I added paginated: true to the GraphQL schema is because I was getting the error I added above.

Comment: Let's follow-up on the Fauna Forums (https://forums.fauna.com/t/lambda-expects-an-array-with-1-elements-array-contains-4/2195) until we have a solution, and then close out the conversation here. SO isn't really meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the query you provided, I feel the need to point out that the `Match` function performs exact matches. It does not (and cannot) unroll a structured array for you. Neither can the `Ref` function.

You'd need to call `Map` on the `inputdata`, and get results for each id. Then you can `Union` those results together into a single list.

I don't know the exact shape of the data that you're dealing with, so here's a query that works with the pre-populated data available in the Dashboard:

```
Let(
  {
    // the pre-populated data has 3 stores, with ids 301, 302, and 303
    // here, we want the products in stores 301 and 302
    ids: [ 301, 302 ]
  },
  // this is where we combine all of the results
  Union(
    Map(
      // here is where we loop over the list of ids
      Var("ids"),
      Lambda(
        // for each id, run this function's expression
        "id",
        Select(
          // each Paginate call returns a page of results with its own data
          // field, so we have to select those out
          "data",
          Paginate(
            Match(
              Index("products_by_store"),
              // here we compose a reference to a specific store, using the
              // Lambda function's current id
              Ref(Collection("stores"), Var("id"))
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Npte that I've used `Let` to simulate passing an array to the body of a UDF. When you run this query, the result should be:

```
[
  ["avocados", "Conventional Hass, 4ct bag", 3.99],
  ["cilantro", "Organic, 1 bunch", 1.49],
  ["limes", "Conventional, 1 ct", 0.35],
  ["limes", "Organic, 16 oz bag", 3.49],
  ["cups", "Translucent 9 Oz, 100 ct", 6.98],
  ["pinata", "Giant Taco Pinata", 23.99],
  ["pinata", "Original Classic Donkey Pinata", 24.99]
]
```